# Behavior of underscore `_` in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I'm exploring Elixir and came across something rather strange about the underscore. We use it to match any variable and discard it, because Elixir considers it permanently unbound:

```
iex(38)> _
** (CompileError) iex:38: unbound variable _
```

But when I assign something to underscore, the value gets echoed the same way it does in the case of normal variable binding:

```
iex(38)> x = 10
10
iex(39)> _ = 10
10
```

What does the shell mean by echoing `10` in the second case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `=` operator returns the value of the RHS after doing the pattern matching. In this case, `10` is ignored as it's assigned to `_`, but the return value of the whole expression is still `10`.

Comment: Thanks! This answer is more relevant because it specifies that the value returned is of the right-hand side.

Answer (score 3):

Every expression in Elixir will return a value. When pattern matching, it will return the right hand side value.

```
_ = 10  # return 10 as RHS value
```

Given that in mind, you can chain the match together.

```
iex(1)> {date, time} = local_time = :calendar.local_time
{{2016, 8, 9}, {7, 43, 11}}

iex(2)> date
{2016, 8, 9}

iex(3)> time
{7, 43, 11}

iex(4)> local_time
{{2016, 8, 9}, {7, 43, 11}}
```

Answer (score 1):

`10` is the result of the expression `_ = 10`.

Everything in Elixir is an expression, so everything returns a value.

Answer (score 0):

Generally in Elixir when you use _ in pattern matching you doesn't care about this value.

Here value of the expression is returned, which is `10`.